# Add image with transparency on top of another on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have three images. I'd like to have [another image](http://www.rendezvousroma.it/new/images/hover-galleria.png) to be on top of the one I'm hovering. And be gone when I mouseleave it. How can I obtain this?
jQuery would be ok, so it's possible to add an animation too :-)

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g1"><img src="blahblah.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g2"><img src="blahblah.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g3"><img src="blahblah.jpg" /></a>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried to set the image to be on hover near every image (so, repeated three times) and then a negative margin-left. By default with a display:none. then with jquery .attr I set I changed the visibility to visible and then to hidden on mouseleave. the problem was that the element to run the hover function was different from the one to be applied on.. And I don't know how to deal with that.. maybe with .find? But how do I combine it with .attr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry i am not sure that i understood your question clearly,but as i think this will help you.

```
<div id="dv1" style="position:relative">
<img id="img1" style="position:absolute" src="image1.jpg">
<img id="img2" src="image2.jpg" width="150">
</div>
//make this div position relative and make images positions as absolute
```

look at this example

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ha3n8/)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest an approach where a hidden element in the page is reused and positioned dynamically on top of the element when hovered.

Animations can be controlled using Jquery on the hidden element

```
$('.toggle img').mouseover(function(){
// Get the current offset of the image
var currentElementOffset=$(this).offset();

// set the current offset of the overlay image
$(".overlay").css({
    top: currentElementOffset.top, 
    left: currentElementOffset.left
});
$(".overlay").fadeIn(500);});
```

And hide the overlay when mouse leaves

```
// Hide the overlay image when the mouse hovers out
$('.overlay').mouseleave(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
});
```

[Check this implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/w4gqj/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
It has some issues when you quickly pass between the images, but it works! :-)